# MonoDevelop: Autocomplete not showing all members?

Tags: autocomplete, monodevelop, d

Linux Mint 17.2 64x

MonoDevelop 5.9.5, writing a D application with D language binding

I've been having a problem with Monodevelop for a long time where it'll just stop showing relevant autocomplete entires. I'll write a class or have one from from a library and sometimes I'll get what's in the class and sometimes I'll only gent entries like `sizeof` (which I think apply to everything). Occasionally I'll get nothing at all.

[Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXLdB.png)

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, I've tried deleting project files, and these solutions work in some cases until I start adding more code and then at some point they break again and I get nothing relevant in my autocomplete pop-ups. I've even tried deleting Monodevelop folders in `.local` `.cache` and `.config` on my system, but the problem persists.

I've been trying to ignore it, and when I had a duel monitor setup it wasn't so bad because I could have references to what I'm working on in another window... but right now I'm `this close` to having zero monitors from getting so frustrated with having to tab around back and forth every 2.5 seconds, I'm just going to lose it and embed my mouse in the screen.

I'd switch to another IDE but I haven't been able to get most of my other options working with D/Dub...

Comment: Yeah, this along with the fact that dkit for sublime text is so good is a lot of the reason I switched. GitHub.com/yazd/dkit. Honestly, sublime feels just like an ide with it!

Comment: :O I got things to work with Sublime and build with dub and everything (after some messing around getting DKit and DCD talking)!! Thanks for the tip! I've been wanting an excuse to try Sublime for a while now. Now I'm just going to go see if there's a git plugin I can use and my life will be complete...

Comment: If you have an answer, remember to post it as an answer to yourself too so people searching it later will see it easily.

Comment: I'm not sure ditching my buggy IDE in favor of a less buggy alternative constitutes an answer to how to fix the buggy IDE...

Comment: I'm not sure it's the IDE what is buggy, but simply the D binding/add-in, because the C# one works flawlessly